# ¿Cómo envío y recibo peticiones a un servidor web mediante RestSharp?

Tags: c#, restsharp

Hace poco que ando buscando una manera de enviar un **POST** a una **URL** utilizando **RestSharp** y leer el resultado, ¿Alguien tiene una idea de cómo lograrlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de haber instalado mediante **Nuget** se requiere importar el paquete a utilizar, aquí un pequeño ejemplo desde consola:

```
using RestSharp;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            RestClient client = new RestClient();
            //Esta es la URL que vamos a visitar
            client.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://www.fredyfx.com");            
            //Definimos la solicitud
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest();            
            //Será un POST el que vamos a enviar  
            request.Method = Method.POST;
            //Ejecutamos la petición y luego obtenemos el contenido.
            //Recibiremos todo el código fuente de la página HTML,
            //tal y como si vieramos desde el navegador, click derecho, ver código fuente.
            Console.WriteLine(client.Execute(request).Content);
            Console.ReadLine();    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: saludos @Error404, esta pregunta/respuesta es un ejemplo para un amigo del sitio :D

Comment: Sigo sin entender el porque de crear una pregunta/respuesta que ya tienes respondida. En caso de que sea para un amigo creo que lo mejor sería enviarle un email. Es simplemente una opinión, pero sigo sin entender muy bien la finalidad de la misma. Un saludo :D

Comment: Pasé por lo mismo @Error404 cuando inicié en el sitio, revisa esto por favor: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/375/se-permite-formular-una-pregunta-y-auto-responderse así tendrás una idea clara :D saludos

Comment: Vale, ahora me ha quedado más claro. Realmente habría millones de pregunta/respuesta que se podrían hacer actualmente y que serían muy útiles para todos.

Comment: buena voz :D vamos a seguir apoyando a todo desarrollador que visita el sitio :D